# Enum backed by enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

I've created an `enum` in Java with each element of the `enum` referencing another `enum`. I've also implemeneted a getter which would return the referenced instance. Nothing weird or wrong, I'd say. The only difference from the usual `enum` implementation is the use of another `enum` as the backing value. I don't use `int` or any other primitive type.

Then I tried to implement the other `enum` in the same way and use the first `enum` as the backing value for its elements. The code compiles fine and nothing appears to be wrong until I called the getter a few times.

See for yourself in the below JUnit test. The assertion fails on the last line.

**Why does it fail?**

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import org.junit.Test;

enum EN {
    DOG(CS.PES),
    CAT(CS.KOCKA);

    CS v;

    EN(CS v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public CS getCS() {
        return this.v;
    }
}

enum CS {
    PES(EN.DOG),
    KOCKA(EN.CAT);

    EN v;

    CS(EN v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public EN getEN() {
        return this.v;
    }
}

public class EnumTest {

    @Test
    public void testValueOfEnum() {
        String zvire = "PES";
        CS pes = CS.valueOf(zvire);
        assertNotNull(pes);
        assertNotNull(pes.getEN()); // OK
        assertNotNull(pes.getEN().getCS()); // FAIL -- getCS() is null
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side comment, an enum is not the best way to create a dictionary - but maybe that was just an example.

Comment: No proof here but since I believe an enum is basicly a class with static instance (or simply constante), one is always create before the other, so the enum instance may not be instranciated yet. Just an idea ;)

Comment: That's because you have a circular reference (A refers to B and B refers to A), which causes a problem with the initialization - to initialize A, first B must be initialized and vice versa.